# Can I make the SharePoint form interactive?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, 2016

I have a custom list where the value in the first column determines which other columns should have value. Or rather, the record type(as selected in the first column) defines what all data I should collect in the form.

I want to continue using the default/designer form for the list.

Is it possible to manipulate the form fields using JavaScript after identifying the value selected in the first column?

EDIT: When I create a new form, I am able to add javascript, and show/hide fields.
However, I can't figure out how to read the fields in javascript.

Comment: Hi entryton, if you know a little of AngularJs, then you can use AngularForms to generate custom forms: https://github.com/Zerg00s/AngularForms Not a super-recommended approach, but at least, you don't need SharePoint Designer in this case.

Comment: Hi Denis, my form has been in user for a long time, and I cannot move to AngularJs now.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have jQuery added to your page, fields can be accessed like so:

```
$("[title='INTERNAL_COLUMN_NAME']").value
```

[image]

For choice, date, lookup fields, etc. the code will be a little different. But this is the main idea.

If you need a special library that handles these complexities for you, you can use the good-old [SPServices JavaScript library](https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/)

**Notes**
If, one day this form migrates to SharePoint Online, there is a very good chance that customizations will be lost.